# Send Multiple forms using doucment.forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onclick

I need to submit the multiple forms in single click on same action using documents.forms. If I would like to send the single form then it can be done by belwo code example :

```
document.forms['form-settings'].action = objAdministrationModule.objExitTags.download_reward_points;
document.forms['form-details'].submit();
```

But how about sending the multiple forms on the same action using single click?

Comment: You could use ajax or set the target of the form to an iframe.

Comment: I need to download the file so ajax is just showing all the content on HTML page instead of downloading that's why I have to use documents.forms

Comment: And the second suggestion?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about that or show some example code?

Comment: Right now the problem is that you leave the page after the first submit? If you set the `target` attribute of each form to a different `iframe` element you can submit multiple forms without leaving the page.